# Teleport an object to specified coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After death, pacman returns to the point of impact with the ghost and starts to rotate. How can I fix this?

```
     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
 
         Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, Speed);
         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);
         if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest)
         {
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                 dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                 dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                 dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                 dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
         }
         Vector2 dir = dest - (Vector2)transform.position;
         GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
         GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);
     }
     bool valid(Vector2 dir)
     {
         Vector2 pos = transform.position;
         RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
         return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
     }
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         if (collision.tag == "Ghost")
             transform.position = new Vector2(14f,11f);
     }
```

Need return to start position, after dead.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmwLZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line :

```
   Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, Speed);
```

Decision:

```
transform.position = PacManStartPoint;
dest = transform.position;
```

How to change the sprite now ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever physics are involved (your re using a `Rigidbody2D`) you do not want to set anything via

```
transform.position = new Vector2(14f,11f);
```

just as you did within `FixedUpdate` rather always only set the value via the `Rigidbody2D` component:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector2(14f,11f);
```

---

Then you also have an `Animator`. Since your movement seems to work in general I guess it's not the issue but still make sure that the animator doesn't hold any keyframe on the position in any animation.

---

In general you should store the reference **once**

```
// Already drag this in via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
[SerializeField] private Animator _animator;

// Also make it possible to adjust the start position via the Inspector
// will make your live easier when changing it ;)
[SerializeField] private Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2(14f,11f);

private void Awake ()
{
    // or get it once as fallback
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    if(!_animator) _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    _rigidbody.position = startPoint;
}
```

and than later re-use them e.g. in

```
_rigidbody.MovePosition(p);
```

and

```
_rigidbody.position = startPoint;
```

and the same for the `_animator`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I rewrote the code,  but pacman stays in the same place.
maybe it's in the rigidbody settings ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmwLZ.jpg